# Reading a file 16 bytes at a time in C

Tags: c, file, hex, offset

I am trying to read a file parsed from a command line argument 16 bytes at a time. I am storing the bytes in an unsigned char array. I am then trying to print the elements in their HEX format and then, if they are printable characters, I am printing them and if not I am printing a dot "." I also would like to print the offset of the byte from the beggining  of the file on each new line but I want to get the rest working before I start working on that. The problem I am having is the file I am reading from is not printing so I don't think I am doing it right. I started out using `fread()` but I think I may be needing to use `fseek()` but I am unsure. If anyone could point me in the right direction or tell me if I'm doing anything wrong I'd appreciate it.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;

    int i, j;

    unsigned char buffer[17];

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        while(fread(buffer, 16, 1, fp) !=0)
        {

            for(i=0; i < 16; i++)
            {
                printf("%X ", buffer[i]);
            }

            for(j = 0; j < 16; j++)
            {
                if(isprint(buffer[j]))
                    printf("%s", buffer[j]);
                else
                    printf("." );
            }

            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
0001:  40 4F 28 37 0B B8 FF 9D 81 5E 2E 73 B5 CC 6A 70 @O(7.....^.s..jp
0010: 0F 30 9C 6E 7E F7 53 E0 C1 5E 9A 38 C5 02 F2 33 .0.n .S..^.8...3
```

EDIT: Fixed problem with suggestions. Was opening file in text mode instead of binary. Changed read mode to `"rb"` and code is working correctly now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to open the file in binary mode, using fseek/ftell on a file in text mode gives erratic values.

So open the file with

```
fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
```

also good practice is to always check if a function succeeded by checking the return value, in this case `if (fp != NULL) ...`

Instead of reading 16 byte chunks read 1 byte 16 times, otherwise if the file length is not evenly dividable by 16 you miss the last bytes

```
if ( fp != NULL )
{
  int read = 0;
  while((read = fread(buffer, 1, 16, fp)) > 0)
  {
    for(i=0; i < read; i++)
    {
    ...
  }
  fclose(fp);
}
```

IOW no need to for the outer `while (feof(fp)) ...`

in

```
printf("%s", buffer[j]);
```

you are not using the correct format specifier, buffer[j] is a character, not a string so write

```
printf("%c", buffer[j]);
```

EDIT: if you are not in some embedded environment with minimal stack reading 16 bytes at a time is not so effective, you can just as might read 2k or some bigger size to read faster.

Comment: Ahh ok, I see where I went wrong. Fixed it an it is now printing correctly. Now I'm going to start working on the file offset. Do you know if this would be done with `fseek()` or `fread()` as well?

Comment: @wh33lybrdy use fseek to position in file. you can specify an offset either from start or end depending on the second parameter e.g. SEEK_END. If you have more questions it is better to post them than continue editing this one since after a while this question becomes very confusing to read.